# busybox - how to list process priority?

Tags: busybox, ps

How to list process priority on an embedded linux with busybox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Busybox can be compiled with `ENABLE_FEATURE_PS_ADDITIONAL_COLUMNS` which will enable `nice` among others. Then you can do, for example:

```
busybox ps -o pid,nice,user,args
```

---

POSIX

- user, group, comm, args, pid, ppid, pgid, tty, vsz

`ENABLE_FEATURE_PS_TIME`

- etime, time

`ENABLE_FEATURE_PS_ADDITIONAL_COLUMNS`

- nice, rgroup, ruser, pcpu (although pcpu seems to be commented out)

---

Non-POSIX

- rss

`ENABLE_SELINUX`

- label

Comment: BusyBox `ps` also seems to support `stat` as a field to show the process status

Answer (score 3):

If you have a cut-down Linux distribution where ps and top does not give you priority information,  you can parse the stat file of proc for your process ID to get the priority information.

```
cat /proc/PID/stat | awk '{print "priority " $18 " nice " $19}'
```

The values at position 18 and 19 of stat file represent priority and nice

For more: https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc